# How to safely back up files that may be in use?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2016

I am currently running a windows server (Server 2016), with a continuous service running - whose data I would like to backup regularly.

I'm looking for a solution to backup this data, without risking any downtime for the service. The situation is as follows:

- Data is stored in flat-files in windows folders. I wish to copy the files to make a backup of them.
- The service that uses the data, may read/write from the files at any time - but does not continuously keep the files locked.
- Failing to successfully backup the files is more acceptable than causing disruption to the service. If a backup misses files due to the service needing them - this is perfectly acceptable.

**How can I safely backup these files, without any risks to the service that uses them, if it decides to read/write them during the backup process?**

Comment: You can use ReFS and take periodically snapshots. More: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview

Comment: @Alex Is it possible to use this to backup just a select number of files? From what I can see it looks like it's for backing up the entire volume. The backups I'm needing to make are in case mistakes are made within an application (so we can restore to before that error was made) - so we need to be able to restore just those individual files that need reverted.

Comment: Yes, snapshots for the volumes. If service that works with those files doesn't have capability to backup with own tools (like mysqldump) then do simple archiving with 7-zip from scheduler if you accept that some files can be skipped

Comment: 7-zip exit with error code if file is in use, you can analyze it in your script such codes and try multiple times until file will be released. Here are 7-zip exit error codes: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm

Comment: @Alex Ah perfect. If just running 7-zip to create an archive has no risk of interupting the service, then that's a perfect answer *(and I'll happily accept it if you put it as one).* Many thanks.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was able to help you and yes, it's a good idea to put it as an answer. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) archive program. It wouldn't fight with files that already in use. You can write a script (batch/cmd/ps) that runs from scheduler on periodic basis and analyze 7-zip's returned [error codes](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm) to decide if you want to wait and retry to archive busy files or simply skip files that are in use by your service.